# How to mimic Google Map's 3-phases bottom sheets in Swift

Tags: ios, google-maps, uikit

The Google Map App has a draggable 3-phases bottom sheet showing details of a selected location.

> Phase 1: A peek view at the bottom, covering part of the map view.
>
> (User pulls up the peek view)
>
> Phase 2: The peek view gradually covers more of the map view with a picture
>   reveals beneath it as the user keep dragging.
>
> (User pulls it up to the top and releases it)
>
> Phase 3: The peek view turns into fullscreen covering the entire map
>   view.

There's an [Android framework](https://github.com/Reline/Google-Maps-BottomSheet) for this use, how can I do this for iOS?

Comment: Hi, Have you solved this task?